# Override module-fedex Carrier.php constructor

Tags: magento2, overrides

I'm going to override module-fedex constructor, here is origin at `\vendor\magento\module-fedex\Model\Carrier.php`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    Security $xmlSecurity,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $configReader,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = [],
    Json $serializer = null
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $scopeConfig,
        $rateErrorFactory,
        $logger,
        $xmlSecurity,
        $xmlElFactory,
        $rateFactory,
        $rateMethodFactory,
        $trackFactory,
        $trackErrorFactory,
        $trackStatusFactory,
        $regionFactory,
        $countryFactory,
        $currencyFactory,
        $directoryData,
        $stockRegistry,
        $data
    );
    $wsdlBasePath = $configReader->getModuleDir(Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR, 'Magento_Fedex') . '/wsdl/';
    $this->_shipServiceWsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'ShipService_v10.wsdl';
    $this->_rateServiceWsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'RateService_v10.wsdl';
    $this->_trackServiceWsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'TrackService_v' . self::$trackServiceVersion . '.wsdl';
    $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
}
```

Here is my custom `carrier.php`

```
namespace Custom\Fedex\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $configReader,
        Json $serializer = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct();
        $wsdlBasePath = $configReader->getModuleDir(Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR, 'Magento_Fedex') . '/wsdl/';
        $this->_shipServiceWsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'ShipService_v10.wsdl';
        $this->_rateServiceWsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'RateService_v10.wsdl';
        $this->_trackServiceWsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'TrackService_v' . parent::$trackServiceVersion . '.wsdl';
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
    }

}
```

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\\Fedex\\Model\\Carrier::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/m22/public_html/app/code/Custom/Fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 14 and at least 18 expected in /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php:172, referer: http://example.com/checkout/`

What is the best practice to override a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding any class you have to pass values in parent :: construct

like you counstruct should be

```
 public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
Security $xmlSecurity,
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
\Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
\Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
\Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $configReader,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
 $productCollectionFactory,
array $data = [],
Json $serializer = null
  ) {
$this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
$this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
parent::__construct(
    $scopeConfig,
    $rateErrorFactory,
    $logger,
    $xmlSecurity,
    $xmlElFactory,
    $rateFactory,
    $rateMethodFactory,
    $trackFactory,
    $trackErrorFactory,
    $trackStatusFactory,
    $regionFactory,
    $countryFactory,
    $currencyFactory,
    $directoryData,
    $stockRegistry,
    $data
);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 16 passed to Magento\\Fedex\\Model\\Carrier::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface, array given, called in /home/m22/public_html/app/code/Custom/Fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 199 and defined in /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php:172, referer: http://example.com/checkout/ 

i have this error if use whole constructor

Comment: Then you dont't need to __construct counstructor in your model
Try after removing counstructor

Comment: but i need to rewrite wsdlBasePath which defined in constructor

Comment: you can get it by making function functionName(){
 $wsdlBasePath = $this->getModuleDir(Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR, 'Magento_Fedex') . '/wsdl/';
}

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, could you please have a look at my post on thehttps://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340018/magento-2-4-2-overriding-carrier-php-of-magento-fedex-module-doesnt-work