# Magento 2.4.2: Overriding Carrier.php of Magento Fedex module doesn't work

Tags: magento2, overrides, fedex

I got to override Magento FedEx Carrier.php in Magento-fedex module which is seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

The structure of the overriden Fedex module under app/code in the project is as below. All the previous custom modules I created the same way are working,but none of them had any Model directory within it.

[image]

registration.php, modul.xml are all edited accordingly. Also ran the upgrade commands. The change doesn't seem to have taken place. Am I overriding the module the way it should be?

di.xml file is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\TypePool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sensitive" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="carriers/fedex/account" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="carriers/fedex/key" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="carriers/fedex/meter_number" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="carriers/fedex/password" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="carriers/fedex/production_webservices_url" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="carriers/fedex/sandbox_webservices_url" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="carriers/fedex/smartpost_hubid" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="environment" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="carriers/fedex/sandbox_mode" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Block\DataProviders\Tracking\DeliveryDateTitle">
        <plugin name="update_delivery_date_title" type="Magento\Fedex\Plugin\Block\DataProviders\Tracking\ChangeTitle"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Popup">
        <plugin name="update_delivery_date_value" type="Magento\Fedex\Plugin\Block\Tracking\PopupDeliveryDate"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Show your di.xml content.

Comment: Please see above di.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can easily extend the class Carrier.php by using preference in di.xml file in  you custom module by extending the core functionality.**

e.g:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier" type="Namespace\YourModule\Model\Carrier"/>
</config>
```

Comment: Nihal, nothing else is necessary?

Comment: as you already created a module use this in your di.xml to override the core class

Comment: Okay, after adding your solution in di.xml, I'm compiling now. Is there a need to have all folders that you see in the custom module PmmFedex?

Comment: yes, if you want to override only the carrier.php class you can just remove all folders from your module accept etc and model.

Comment: dont forget to change the paths that i have used in di.xml

Comment: I already changed the path for type="Namespace\YourModule\Model\Carrier"/ and ran the compile commands no results still

Comment: kindly share you di.xml and what changes you are doing in carrier.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126695/discussion-between-codeforgood-and-nihal-malik).

Comment: Would you mind chatting with me over di.xml?